# Change extension for all files in a folder & its subfolder

Tags: command-line, windows-explorer, xcopy

I am using `XCOPY` the following successfully copies the entire contents of
`\MY SKETCHES 2021` to `\My Sketches (TEXT)`.
This is my command: 
`xcopy C:\Users\terry\Dropbox\Electronics\Arduino\SKETCHES\My Sketches\MY SKETCHES 2021 C:\Users\terry\Dropbox\Electronics\Arduino\SKETCHES\My Sketches\My Sketches (TEXT) /E`

But I want to change the extension of all `.ino` source files to `.txt`. Ideally simultaneously, but I'd be happy enough with two steps, perhaps the second being a RENAME. I see no relevant parameter in `XCOPY`. And the versatile `Bulk Rename Utility` works only on a single folder, not recursively.

Background: this will allow me to view the .ino files on my iPad with Dropbox, which cannot do that despite their being plain text files.
All suggestions gratefully received please.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %F in (`"dir /b/s *.ino"`) do  ren "%F" "%~nF.txt"
```

The usebackq is needed to allow the back quotes in the file set. The delims= is for folders or filenames with embedded spaces. The %~nF expands %F to a file name only, without path or extension.
To check it before you run it, just insert an echo e.g.

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %F in (`"dir /b/s *.ino"`) do echo ren "%F" "%~nF.txt"
```

Edit: That works when entered on a command prompt. In a batch script, it is necessary to double the percent signs e.g.

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%F in (`"dir /b/s *.ino"`) do echo ren "%%F" "%%~nF.txt"
```

Comment: Many thanks, appreciate the fast response. It's a few decades since I used batch files so that's almost certainly why I couldn't get that to work. I assumed the only thing to change was 'dir'. My batch file is this therefore this one-liner:
for /F "usebackq delims=" %F in (`"C:\Users\terry\Dropbox\Electronics\Arduino\SKETCHES - part copy /b/s *.ino"`) do  ren "%F" "%~nF.txt"

Comment: Why such a short time to edit?

Comment: Tried this version too:
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%F in (`"C:\Users\terry\Dropbox\Electronics\Arduino\SKETCHES - part copy /b/s *.ino"`) do echo ren "%%F" "%%~nF.txt"
Also tried the earlier one from command prompt, but got
The system cannot find the file C:\Users\terry\Dropbox\Electronics\Arduino\SKETCHES - part copy /b/s *.ino.